# mysql insertion not working

Tags: php, mysql

i know this is the very basic question but i have been stuck into this for 3 hours and could not figure out whats wrong.
Can any body please tell me that whats wrong in this query?

```
insert into user_to_deliverable set d_id = 1 u_id = 4
```

I am having the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'u_id = 4' at line 1
```

I corrected the query according to the answer but it is running only on phpmyadmin not inserting through code, here is my code

```
foreach($_POST['user'] as $k=>$v) {

      echo    $ins_u_deliverable =   "insert into user_to_deliverable set d_id = ".$_POST['dlvrbl_id'].", u_id    =   $v "."<br />";

      mysql_query($ins_u_deliverable);
    }
```

the array for user is

```
[user] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
    )
```

Comment: **STOP** You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Read up and learn about them before you go any farther with this code, or you're just begging to get your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 2):

Set syntax typically looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table SET a=1, b=2, c=3
```

I'm guessing you are missing a comma, i.e. your query should be:

```
insert into user_to_deliverable set d_id = 1, u_id = 4
```

If that doesn't work, make sure all of the elements you are specifying exist.

EDIT: Your syntax now appears to be correct, for troubleshooting I would make sure you are getting accurate values for

```
$_POST['dlvrbl_id'] and $v
```

to make sure that your variables are all correct.

Comment: Could you please edit this answer so that I can remove my downvote, which is incorrect?  Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough; but what is my answer missing? @baig772 I see your edit, can you be more specific about what is happening now? Is the error no longer occurring, and is there a different one in its place?

Comment: yes that was the problem that I forgot to enter commas but then the main problem was because of **br** and now my code is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to **insert a record**?

You have to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_to_deliverable (d_id, u_id)
VALUES (1, 4)
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are combining the syntax from two different commands INSERT and UPDATE to create a new command that doesn't exist in SQL.

The correct syntax for INSERT:

```
 INSERT INTO user_to_deliverable (d_id, u_id) VALUES (1, 4)
```

Comment: He's not. SET with INSERT is perfectly fine in MySQL. It's also more readable.

Comment: Just checked the MySQL and, as you state, this hybrid format is, in fact supported by MySQL.  So, consider my post to say "shouldn't" in place of "doesn't".

Comment: I was gonna downvote this for being incorrect, but it isn't: you explicitly state in *SQL*, which is true. That makes it more a matter of opinion (which is more readable, should you use INSERT.. VALUES for portability, etc.)

Comment: @BaylesJ: For what it's worth, it is incorrect.  I hadn't checked MySQL's alternate syntax when I wrote the response.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem that `<br />` was making the problem, removed it and query just going fine :)
Thanks all :)

Comment: If applicable, you should pick a correct answer if you feel there is one :)